# why does the argument label become irrelevant in this Swift code?

Tags: swift, function, types

My understanding from the [Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) is that argument *labels*,  not just argument *datatypes*, are intrinsic to the function signature at compile time. Thus, the compiler understands that these two versions of `f` have different types: they both take one `String` argument, but the label is different.

```swift
func f(foo str : String) -> String { "foo" }
func f(bar str : String) -> String { "bar" }

f(foo: "hi") // "foo"
f(bar: "hi") // "bar"
```

I’m perplexed, however, by the behavior below. `g` and `h` also have different types, because they have different argument labels. But this code compiles and runs, even though the argument label is missing:

```swift
func f(foo str : String) -> String { "foo" }
func f(bar str : String) -> String { "bar" }

func g(foo str : String) -> String { f(foo: str) }
func h(bar str : String) -> String { f(bar: str) }

(0 < 100 ? g : h)("hello") // "foo" (why?)
```

But if we introduce a second `h` with a different argument label, the code cannot compile, because now we have two conflicting types of `h`:

```swift
func f(foo str : String) -> String { "foo" }
func f(bar str : String) -> String { "bar" }

func g(foo str : String) -> String { f(foo: str) }
func h(bar str : String) -> String { f(bar: str) }
func h(foo str : String) -> String { f(foo: str) }

(0 < 100 ? g : h)("hello") // ambiguity error
```

My question: why, in the second example, does the Swift compiler take a more lenient view of type checking? I understand that there is no type ambiguity. But the behavior still seems to break with Swift’s very strong policy about return types of expressions needing to match.

If we believe that argument labels are part of the type signature, then an expression like `0 < 100 ? g : h` shouldn’t even compile, because `g` and `h` have different argument labels, and hence different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fact: any function in Swift can be reduced to a closure, and they actually are when passed around. `f` and `g` and `h` can all be reduced to closures of type `(String) -> String`.

Next, your `(some_computation)("hello")` code what in fact does is to tell to the compiler that you want to create an anonymous function (aka closure), that you call with the "hello" argument.

And due to the above, `(0 < 100 ? g : h)("hello")` instructs the Swift compiler to transform the `g` and `h` functions to closures of type `(String) -> String`. And closures don't have argument labels, thus any function, with any label, matches.

However, in the problematic code snippet, the compiler can no longer uniquely identify which `h` "overload" to use. Thus, it bails out.

If you want to unambiguously match one of the `h` functions, then you need to fully qualify it:

```swift
(0 < 100 ? g : h(foo:))("hello")
```

The rules work the same for member functions, as long as the compiler can decide which closure to pass along, it will match the function name, without having to specify its complete name.

Main point is that in Swift you don't circulate functions, you circulate closures. There's no way to specify a variable, or a function argument, or a property, to have labeled arguments.

Comment: "Fact: any function in Swift can be reduced to a closure, and they actually are when passed around." Is that really true today? I thought closures and functions were currently managed separately as an implementation detail. (I may be out of the loop on this.)

Comment: @RobNapier internally, they might be handled differently by the compiler, for example instance functions get converted to closures that capture `self`, however at a high level the developer circulates closures.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea about the `h(foo:)` notation!